# How to filter group membership from the ldap server?

Tags: ubuntu, group, ldap

Context : We have a Ubuntu 12.04 with authentication done on a ldap server.

Unfortunately, one (ldap) user belongs to a (ldap) group named "admin".

I know there is the option nss_initgroups_ignoreusers to list the users I don't want to be looked for from the ldap. But couldn't find any equivalent for groups.

How could I specify ldap groups not to be used on this installation?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of would be including a filter with your `nss_base_group` entry. Depending on what group structure you're using, you might need to replace `cn` with `gid` or something else. You might need to change the base and scope of the search as well depending on your system.

```
nss_base_group  ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com?one?(!(cn=admin))
```